# How to run R code more than once for multiple n

Tags: r

I have the following code in R which runs fine.

```
n = 2
funs = expand.grid(rep(list(1:10), n))
```

However I want to run this for multiple n at the same time. I want to run it for n= 2,3,4,5,6,7,8
So I tried this, but it didn't work. How should I modify my code?

```
n = [2:8]
funs = expand.grid(rep(list(1:10), n))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_fun = function(n) expand.grid(rep(list(1:10), n))
a <- lapply(2:8, my_fun)
```

The function produces a list of dataframes, one for each parameter value. To access the values for n = 2, the first parameter value, you could use `a[1]`.

Comment: thanks, just out of curiousity.. if I wanted to get the row count of each df, how could I do that?

Comment: You could look at `str(a)` or the function here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27336263/6851825